# Is SATA 3 backwards compatible?

Tags: sata

I am getting a SSD but the only cheap ones are SATA 2, and my motherboard has only SATA 3 slots. Will it work with my motherboard and do I need to buy a SATA 2 or 3 cable for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is and has always been.

Comment: not much more to be said... :P

Comment: Both backwards and forwards compatible.