# SSD SATA III with motherboard SATA I

Tags: ssd, sata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is SATA 3 backwards compatible?](https://superuser.com/questions/223512/is-sata-3-backwards-compatible)
>   [Are SATA II and SATA 3.0 Gbps compatible?](https://superuser.com/questions/300519/are-sata-ii-and-sata-3-0-gbps-compatible)

I want to buy SSD and connect it to my super old system: motherboard with SATA1 (yes SATAI = SATA 1.5Gbit/s), chipset is nForce3 250.I want to buy SSD SATA3 with looking into future, so my question is SSD SATA3 can work with SATA1. I know that cables is compatible but... Anyone have some expierence about that ?
I'm thinking about OCZ vertex 4.

Comment: Yeah, but you certainly won't get SATA III speeds.

Comment: This is q. implicitly connected with another questions: is AHCI mode will be availible? Is TRIM function will be availible on Windows 7 if SSD can't work with AHCI and only in IDE mode ? I'm asking about correct and bugless work with this configuration. Another case, that as I know that usually random access to disk more important and anyway I can see power of SSD even at SATA I. Also I know that my chipset is not so good and asking is it enough to have bugless work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will work, but that means the SSD upgrade probably isn't worth it. it doesn't matter how fast the drive is if it has to get/put data 1/4 speed.

Comment: True. However I think I can see power of SSD because my current system  so slow. I'm going to buy new PC in 3-4 months, but know I have to reinstall windows and decide to improve my work in some way. Also I saw many videos about SSD at old systmes, so in any case it should be faster then now. ANd generally my question is about is it good move from my side to inject SSD to CURRENT PC .